# How to fire Event from firefox / Chrome Console on a element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been trying to do this for past 6 hours , I have looked up all other SO question and still not help, all answers are about either about event dispatcher or getting the element then execute .click() on it.

None of them are working.

Is there any way I can execute under laying javascript associated with event or trigger the given events like mouseover, mouseup from the console ?

This is an adult site, I am trying to learn web automation.

[image]

Comment: Well, on most elements, `.click()` _should_ work. (For example, here on SO, open your console and paste `document.querySelector('.my-profile').click();` to access your profile). Can you create a minimal code example of the HTML and JS similar to the website elements you're trying to interact with? So we can reproduce it and see what might not be working. Also, sometimes, there are easier ways than going throught the UI. For example on the website you're mentioning, you can set the volume with localStorage: `localStorage.setItem('player_volume', '{"volume":15,"isMuted":false}');` and reload.

Comment: It is possible that none of it is working because it was coded to ignore non-organic events. If the event handlers are set to check for `e.isTrusted` your event dispatches and `.click()`s may be getting ignored by design. Just a thought.